# How to set hierarchy on Django objects of the same class?

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a web for translators in Django. Each translator can speak different languages on different levels. So translator 1 can speak English on level 'professional', translator 2 can speak English on level 'native'.

There are four different `Levels`. (Level is a model)

```
class Level(models.Model):
    LEVEL_CHOICES = (
        ('unknown', _('Unknown')),
        ('standard', _('Standard level')),
        ('professional', _('Professional level')),
        ('native', _('Native speaker level')),
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=LEVEL_CHOICES, blank=False, null=False,
                            help_text=_('Choose a level'))

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.get_name_display())
```

And model `LanguageLevel`:

```
class LanguageLevel(models.Model):
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language,
                                 help_text=_('Choose a language'), related_name='language_levels')
    level = models.ForeignKey(Level,
                              help_text=_('Choose a level of the language'))
    price_multiplier = models.FloatField(default=0.0,
                                         help_text=_('Type a price multiplier'))

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}: {}'.format(self.language, self.level)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('level', 'language'),)
```

Now what's the problem. The problem is that if I want to get, for example, translator speaking `English` on level 'standard', in fact, I want to get translators speaking `English` on level either 'standard', 'professional' or 'native' because those, who can speak 'native' can speak 'standard' too.

There are many situations in my project like this so I would like to simplify this.

So `unknown`<`standard`<`professional`<`native`. Now if I try to get all translator speaking English on `standard` level, I want to get `professional` and `native` too.

Could you give me advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an integerfield instead of charfield. This makes querying on level simple.

```
LEVEL_CHOICES = (
    (0, _('Unknown')),
    (1, _('Standard level')),
    (2, _('Professional level')),
    (3, _('Native speaker level')),
)

level = models.IntegerField(choices=LEVEL_CHOICES, default=0,
                        help_text=_('Choose a level'))
```

I'm not sure why you need the Level model. I would have just put everything into LanguageLevel.

Your query would look something like this:

```
LanguageLevel.objects.filter(level__gte=1, language__name='English')
```